# Why is this code taking up so much memory?

Tags: c++, sfml

I ran into this problem when I was trying to draw each pixel in the window separately, so here is the simpler version of my problem. When I run this code, the process memory starts to increase rapidly until it reaches 365 MB and stops increasing. Why is this taking up so much memory and what can I do to fix this issue?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window{ sf::VideoMode{ 1024, 960 }, "Pixels", sf::Style::Close };

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event sfmlEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(sfmlEvent)) {
            if (sfmlEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < window.getSize().x; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < window.getSize().y; ++j) {
                sf::RectangleShape rect{ { 1.0f, 1.0f } };
                rect.setPosition(i, j);
                window.draw(rect);
            }
        }

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how much would you expect?

Comment: there is more than your code in an application, especially when using libraries like this

Comment: I would expect it to be pretty low, somewhere near 20 MB or so, since all the `sf::RectangleShape` objects are being destroyed every time and there is no reason for memory to pile up.

Comment: "_When I run this code, the process memory starts to increase rapidly until it reaches 365 MB and stops increasing._" - Just because you didn't expect it, it's not necessarily a bad behavior.

Comment: The resident size is indeed around 20MB. The virtual size is pretty much meaningless. It's all libraries code (not data). It is shared between many applications and even if this is the only application, most of this code is not going to be ued in this small program. So it will sit on the disk and never get loaded to RAM.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is creating a new sf::RectangleShape for every pixel every frame. The sf::RectangleShape class has 4 floating point numbers for the x, y, width, and height. The total amount of rectangles created every frame would be 983,040, and each would consist of four floats, meaning that you are creating close to 4 million floats every frame taking up a TON of memory. I'm not sure what it is your trying to do exactly, but if you want precise control over individual pixels, you should be doing that on the GPU using OpenGL and maybe some shaders.